# How to unlock admin locked preference panes

Tags: macos, preferences

My lovely work locks certain preference panes, but I need to access a couple things. I've found a way to do this before, but can't seem to find it online.

I've dumped the managed preferences plist.  I thought there was a terminal command that could be used to make that work?

Answer (score 4):

If your employer is locking preference panes, it is for reasons they have determined are necessary for their (and your) protection.

Most modern MDM (Mobile Device Management) systems can detect such subversions, self-repair if successfully subverted, and report back to the administrators.

Be forewarned, attempts to subvert such restrictions placed on your computer, (which I assume your *employer* owns, not you,) can in some cases be a firing offense.

One recourse you have is to ask if certain restrictions can be relaxed if they interfere with your job duties.